# Android camera: need to turn FLASH_MODE_TORCH on automatically

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, flashlight

My code must automatically turn on the flashlight LED when the light is insufficient.

I can turn the flashlight on in the torch mode:

```
camera = Camera.open();
final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
// ...
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

But I must not turn it on when it is not needed.

**How do I find out, programmatically, whether I need to turn the flashlight on?**

In other words, how can my application know if there's enough light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at these two SO posts for checking, what light level is around you:
[Lightsensor Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429614/android-camera-get-light-sensor-value) and [Brightness of surrounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738294/android-detect-brightness-amount-of-light-in-phones-surroundings-using-the-c)

But **you** have to decide, at which light level you'll turn the flashlight on.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish have it turn on automatically while taking a photo if the light is insufficient, then FLASH_MODE_AUTO should do the trick for you

Comment: FLASH_MODE_AUTO does not turn on the light for the preview mode, so it did not solve my problem.